# Android: Open Facebook profile in app from username

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, android-intent

How can I open Facebook profile from username? Or which request should I use in Android to get (and open) Facebook profile.

```
Intent intent;

try {
    activity.getPackageManager()
            .getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0); // Checks if FB is even installed.
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("fb://profile/" + famous)); // Trys to make intent with FB's URI
} catch (Exception e) {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/" + famous)); // catches and opens a url to the desired page
}

activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Tried this but didn't work with username (goes to user's - user which is logged in - wall) and id (static inserted, shows error - couldn't load this profile)...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to open, as  `fb://profile/` and `fb://page/` no longer work, but `fb://facewebmodal/f?href=[YOUR_FACEBOOK_PAGE]` can be used

```
public static Intent newFacebookIntent(PackageManager pm, String url) {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
  try {
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
    if (applicationInfo.enabled) {
      uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + url);
    }
  } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
  }
  return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
}
```

`url` : The full URL to the Facebook page or profile.

`pm`  : `Context#getPackageManager()`